# fullcalendar set color of dropped div

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

This is my full calendar implementation:

```
$(renderTo).fullCalendar({
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
        axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
        defaultView:view,
        firstHour:  7,
        firstDay:   1,
        titleFormat: {
            month: 'MMMM yyyy',
            week: "MMM d[ yyyy]{ '&#8212;'[ MMM] d yyyy}",
            day: 'dddd, d MMM yyyy',
        },
        columnFormat: {
            month: 'ddd',
            week: 'ddd, dd.MM',
            day: 'dddd, dd.MM'
        },
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        buttonText: {
            prev: '&lt;',
            next: '&gt;',
            prevYear: '&laquo;',
            nextYear: '&raquo;',
            today:    'dziś',
            month:    'miesiąc',
            week:     'tydzień',
            day:      'dzień'
        },
        monthNames: ['Styczeń', 'Luty', 'Marzec', 'Kwiecień', 'Maj', 'Czerwiec', 'Lipiec', 'Sierpień', 'Wrzesień', 'Październik', 'Listopad', 'Grudzień'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Sty', 'Lut', 'Mar', 'Kwi', 'Maj', 'Cze', 'Lip', 'Sie', 'Wrz', 'Paź', 'Lis', 'Gru'],
        dayNames: ['Niedziela', 'Poniedziałek', 'Wtorek', 'Środa', 'Czwartek', 'Piątek', 'Sobota'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Nie', 'Pon', 'Wto', 'Śro', 'Czw', 'Pią', 'Sob'],
        editable: true,
        eventDrop: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,allDay,revertFunc) {
            result = updateEvent(event.id,dayDelta,minuteDelta,allDay,'false');
            if (result == true) {
            } else {
                revertFunc();
                alert(result);
            }
        },
                eventMouseover: function( event, jsEvent, view ) { 
                    var details = getDetails(event.id, $(this));
                                    },
        eventResize: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,revertFunc) {
            result = updateEvent(event.id,dayDelta,minuteDelta,'false','true');
            if (result == true) {
                //alert('Zmiana została zapisana');
            } else {
                revertFunc();
                alert(result);
            }
        },
        droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
        drop: function(date, allDay) {
            var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
            copiedEventObject.start     = date;
            copiedEventObject.allDay    = allDay;

            //$time
            result  = addNewEvent(copiedEventObject.start.toISOString(),originalEventObject.title,originalEventObject.allDay);
            if (result == true) {
                var currentView = $(renderTo).fullCalendar('getView');
                renderCalendar(renderTo,currentView.name);
            } else {
                alert(result);
            }
        },
        events: {
            url:    '/schedule/getCalendarEvents',
            data: {
                agent_id: <?php echo $this->user_info->id; ?>,
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Wystąpił problem w czasie pobierania danych!');
            },
            //color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
            textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
        },

        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) $('#loading').show();
            else $('#loading').hide();
        }
    });
```

and I want to drop this div:

```
<div class="external-event ui-draggable" style="position: relative;background-color:red">sdf</div>
```

How to change background-color dynamicaly when droping event wiht dropped div

so in this example I would like have new event bg-color:red

Answer (score 4):

i had same problem and i solved it.
The HTML for the events:

```
<div id='external-events'>
    <h4>Events</h4>
    <div class='fc-event' style="background-color: red;" data-color='red'>Event 1</div>
    <div class='fc-event' style="background-color: blue;" data-color='blue'>Event 2</div>
    <div class='fc-event' style="background-color: green;" data-color='green'>Event 3</div>
    <div class='fc-event' style="background-color: yellow;" data-color='yellow'>Event 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And javascript code:

```
/* initialize the external events
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

$('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {

// store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
$(this).data('event', {
  title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
  stick: true, // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
  color: $(this).data('color')
});

// make the event draggable using jQuery UI
$(this).draggable({
  zIndex: 999,
  revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
  revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
});

});
```

You can test [here](https://jsfiddle.net/romanlezama/4t2uogng/).

Answer (score 0):

Use like below in the drop event
copiedEventObject.backgroundColor = "#666666";

Answer (score 0):

Use the `element` on the `eventRender` from fullcalendar.

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/

Answer (score 0):

HTML Query

```
 <div id="mydrag">
                    <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>
                    <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
                    <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
                    <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
                    <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
 </div>
```

Javascript Query

```
<style>
 #mydrag>.fc-event{
                background-color: red;
                color: white;
 }
 </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using v6 of FullCalendar (may work with earlier versions but not in a position to check), I've used [eventReceive](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventReceive) to add the colour to the event being created.

> eventReceive
>
> Called when an external draggable element with associated event data
> was dropped onto the calendar. Or an event from another calendar.

```
eventReceive: (eventDropped) => {
    eventDropped.event.setProp('backgroundColor', 'red');
},
```

As part of the information being sent is the event being created, you can set various things on that event before it's rendered.  In the example above, it's just setting it to a fixed colour.

If you want to pass a colour from the original element, you can add an attribute with something like

```
<div id="eventType1" data-color="red"
```

As you also get the element the data was dragged from, you can use this attribute to set the colour...

```
eventDropped.event.setProp('backgroundColor', 
             eventDropped.draggedEl.getAttribute('data-color'));
```